# (Unity3d) How do I make a "move pad" on the screen? (Mobile)

Tags: mobile, input, unity-game-engine

In my game you can control the character by moving left and right, jumping and attacking. (This is a mobile game) I have a button that I use to jump and attack, which is easy because I just make a button and jump or attack with OnClick(). But for moving, I don't know how to find out if the user is pressing the button, I only know when it is clicked. How can I find this out? thanks.

If you dont understand what Im trying to say, basically here is my web game: http://dugelstudios.weebly.com/weapon-plus-plus.html

(Does not work on chrome, using safari or internet exploror)

and i am porting it to mobile, and i dont know how to make the player move left and right with touch controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other MonoBehaviour methods such as [OnMouseOver](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html) to check if a button is pressed, [OnMouseEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html) when a user begins to press a button, and [OnMouseExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseExit.html) to check if a user has released the button.
You can also use [OnMouseUpAsButton](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUpAsButton.html) to mimic the behaviour of Button.onClick

For draggings movements, (like movement. For example, if you have a thumbstick, or something similar for movement), you can use [OnMouseDrag](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html).

Also, completely unrelated to your question, but something you have mentioned, you can enable NPAPI to enable WebPlayer builds in Chrome.

Just paste **chrome://flags/#enable-npapi** in a new tab in Chrome, and click the "Enable" button to get it running

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a thumb stick asset the standard Unity asset pack that's available on the [store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351).